# proper Velocity.js syntax?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, velocity

I'm attempting to transition some of my CSS animations to Velocity animations due to some sluggishness in certain browsers. However I can't seem to get the syntax right. Here is the css:

```
.container .first-section .first-section-buttons,
.container .second-section .second-section-buttons {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(400px);
    transform: translateY(400px);
}

container .first-section.isShown .first-section-buttons,
.container .second-section.isShow .second-section-buttons  {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
    transition: -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(.165, .84, .44, 1), opacity .7s cubic-bezier(.165, .84, .44, 1);
    transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(.165, .84, .44, 1), opacity .7s cubic-bezier(.165, .84, .44, 1);
}
```

How would I properly re-create this animation in Velocity.js?